# Merge two DataFrames on certain columns

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to merge two DataFrames based on a key but only merge certain columns. See my example below but I wish to merge the `Colour` from `df1` but not the `Id`

`df1` is:

```
Id My_ID Colour
NaN     1     Red
```

`df2` is:

```
Id My_ID Colour
1       1     Blue
```

Result should be:

```
Id My_ID Colour
1       1     Red
```

Essentially  taking just `Colour` from `df1` and merging this with `Id` and `My_Id` from `df2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [265]: df = pd.merge(df1[['My_ID','Colour']], df2[['Id','My_ID']], on='My_ID')
In [268]: df
Out[268]: 
   Id  My_ID Colour
0   1      1    Red
```